# Share datacontext / inject dependencies Entity Framework 6 Code First

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

How does one share the datacontext of `Entity Framework 6.1.1.` and inject dependencies (I use `Ninject` ) like repositories, since EF6 supports repositories and UoW out of the box?

All I can find are SO question and blogpost/articles at least 3 years old. But nothing about EF6, and the current situation which is repositories and UoW being supported out of the box.

The solution contains 2 projects, one is the web project (`asp.net-mvc`), the other one is the class library acting as the datalayer. The datalayer is based on `Code First`.

I did create repositories, but didn't realize it was already supported out of the box.

I installed ninject.mvc5 and this is what I registered:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IOrderRepository>().To<OrderRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>().InRequestScope();
        }
```

So I guess I need to re-factor my code and remove the repositories. But I don't know what should replace them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repositories are your `DbSet`s inside the `DbContext`. The `DbContext` is your UoW.

Whenever the UoW was used before, you use `DbContext` now. And you **no longer pass individual repositories around, you pass the whole `DbContext`** (it was, frankly, unusual habit before to pass individual repositories, although many people did that).

This now is sufficient then

```
        kernel.Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

The `ApplicationDbContext` is then injected via constructor injection to upper layer classes where applicable.

Comment: Hi, could you show me an example how one of those upper classes should look like? And do I need to install ninject in the class library project as well?